# Barach v.s. Kalal/Arar

Tags: blessing, commentaries, curse

Bereshit 12:3 spreaks about: '*va.a.var.cha m'va.ra.chey.cha u.me.ka.lel.cha a.or*' While in Devarim 30:19 it states: '*ha.be.ra.cha v'hak.la.la*'.

Are kalal and arar the same thing? As both seem to be the opposite of bracha (blessing).

I once learned that in the case of tov v'rah (good and wrong/bad) rah could be understand as the absence of HaShem, while in the case of what seems to be understand as 'good' His presence/will is felt.

Could one understand blessing (barach) en curse (arar/kalal) the same way? 
Because in the cases of blessing 'good seems to befall upon those who are blessed' while in the cases of cursings 'bad or evil seems to befall/come upon those who are cursed', With HaShem (if one heeds His voice; Devarim 28) one befalls good, while without HaShem (if one don't heed His voice) one befalls bad? (life and death to put it in a extreem way; are good and bad things that could befall us).

HaShem is presenting to Am Yirael two approaches - the derech hatov and the derech ha'rah. If one chooses the good approach, then he will receive a lot of reward (blessing)... and the same seems to apply to a bad approach, then one will receive some form of punishment in the form of curses will come upon him. So a live with HaShem, with His presence in it, is good and a blessing.

Presence v.s. absence?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Malbi"m](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32825&st=&pgnum=120&hilite=) Arar refers to curses that actually cause a negative change. Kalal refers to cursing someone in a degrading manner.

Comment: But what i really want to know is if the assumption being made has reliability.

Comment: Sorry, I would have just added it as a comment to your question, since it doesn't answer the main point, but I'm not able to do that yet.

Comment: @Levi, your question post has two questions in it. (1) "Are kalal and arar the same thing? As both seem to be the opposite of bracha (blessing)." (2) The rest of it thereafter. This answer seems to answer #1. Did you really mean to ask #1?

Comment: @msh210, yes i did, thats why i thanked I K